# Missing Fixed Frame in My Model

Tags: gazebo, rviz, ros-melodic

Why isn't Gazebo 9 displaying the tip's frame? Using RViz, you can view the frame as shown in the below image. In addition, I can't see the link listed under the model in Gazebo. There seems to be no visualisation of fixed frames. Gazebo only displays one fixed joint, which connects the world and base link.

[image]

```
<link name="tip"/>
<joint name="tip_joint" type="fixed">
   <parent link="mid_link"/>
   <child link="tip"/>
   <origin xyz="0 0 ${height2}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't used Gazebo (still), but in looking around online [it looks like](https://answers.ros.org/question/315166/gazebo-not-loading-certain-links/?answer=315253#post-id-315253):

> You need the inertial tag to properly load a model in Gazebo (but not for rivz, that's why you are able to visualize the urdf with rviz)

There's another question that asks, ["How to use Gazebo without the inertial tag"](https://answers.ros.org/question/337202/how-to-use-gazebo-without-the-inertial-tag/) and [the answer there is](https://answers.ros.org/question/337202/how-to-use-gazebo-without-the-inertial-tag/?answer=337267#post-id-337267):

> You can try just using rviz instead of using gazebo. The rviz models don't require physics attributes.

Any other answers that I find looking around online for "visualizing reference frames in Gazebo" all seem to refer to visualizing *link* frames in Gazebo, and again it looks like the links need to have physics to be represented.

Your joint may not be showing up because your link isn't getting loaded, which may then cause the joint to fail; [here's another question](https://answers.ros.org/question/304213/gazebo-cant-find-the-link-after-declaring-it/) that mentions an error when Gazebo tries to load their URDF:

> Failed to build tree: child link [ired1] of joint [ired1_joint] not found This is what I get when I try to launch my gazebo simulation. It is strange because I have declared all the joints and links:
>
> ```
> [ERROR] [1537878063.001524419]: Failed to build tree: child link [ired1] of joint [ired1_joint] not found
> ```

And a comment in response says,

> The Gazebo URDF parser plainly ignores links without the required dynamics-related elements. Whether they are necessary or not, it is a common cause for error messages relating to missing links and/or joints with Gazebo.

Is Gazebo throwing any errors?

Comment: http://sdformat.org/tutorials?tut=sdformat_urdf_extensions&cat=specification&#fixed-joint-lumping is also a good reference for understanding what happens to links without mass and inertial properties.

Comment: (+1) great info. I didn't get any errors.